# Cant apply rest controllers junit tests correctly

Tags: java, spring, rest, junit

I am trying to apply junit test for my rest controllers.
I've tried to apply junit 4 but I got 404 error instead 200.
It looks like something is not initialized but cant't figured what.

Here is  tutorial I have tried to apply.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8S8o46avgAw

I also tried some different tutorials with junit 5 but the result was the same.

Here you can find the whole project.
https://github.com/WojciechWeg/tiny-bank/tree/tests

Just before publishing this post I've applied the following:

```
    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(customerController)
                .build();

        customer = new Customer("Jan","Kowalski",new Date(),"Marszalkowska",new ArrayList<>());

        customerService.createNewCustomer(customer);

        System.out.println("Customers from service: "+ customerService.getAllCustomers());
    }
```

But the result of it is:

```
Customers from service: []
```

So it returns nothing. Above snippet is not in repo link.

Rest controller class:

```
package com.tinybank.tinybankapi.controllers;

import com.tinybank.tinybankapi.model.Account;
import com.tinybank.tinybankapi.model.Customer;
import com.tinybank.tinybankapi.model.CustomerResource;
import com.tinybank.tinybankapi.services.CustomerService;

import org.springframework.hateoas.Link;
import org.springframework.hateoas.Resources;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.MvcUriComponentsBuilder;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.ServletUriComponentsBuilder;

import javax.validation.Valid;
import java.net.URI;
import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(CustomerController.BASE_URL)
public class CustomerController {

    public static final String BASE_URL = "api/customers";

    private final CustomerService customerService;

    public CustomerController(CustomerService customerService) {
        this.customerService = customerService;
    }

    @GetMapping
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public ResponseEntity<Resources<List<Customer>>> getListOfCustomers() {
        Resources<List<Customer>> resources = new Resources(customerService.getAllCustomers());
        String uri = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequest().build().toUriString();
        resources.add(new Link(uri,"self"));
        return ResponseEntity.ok(resources);
    }

    @GetMapping({"/{id}"})
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public Customer getCustomer(@PathVariable Long id) {
        return customerService.getCustomerById(id);
    }

    @DeleteMapping({"/{id}"})
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public void deleteCustomer(@PathVariable Long id) {
        customerService.deleteCustomerById(id);
    }

    @PostMapping
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public ResponseEntity<CustomerResource> createNewCustomer(@RequestBody @Valid Customer Customer) {

        Customer customer = customerService.createNewCustomer(Customer);
        URI uri = MvcUriComponentsBuilder.fromController(getClass())
                .path("/{id}")
                .buildAndExpand(customer.getId())
                .toUri();

        return ResponseEntity.created(uri).body(new CustomerResource(customer));
    }

    @PutMapping({"/{id}/open_account"})
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public void openAccount(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestBody Account account) {
        customerService.openAccount(id, account);
    }

}
```

Test class:

```
package com.tinybank.tinybankapi.controllers;

import com.tinybank.tinybankapi.model.Customer;
import com.tinybank.tinybankapi.services.CustomerService;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.any;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.get;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class CustomerControllerTest {

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Mock
    private CustomerService customerService;

    @InjectMocks
    private CustomerController customerController;

    Customer customer;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(customerController)
                .build();

        customer = new Customer("Jan","Kowalski",new Date(),"Marszalkowska",new ArrayList<>());

        customerService.createNewCustomer(customer);

        System.out.println("Customers from service: "+ customerService.getAllCustomers());

    }

    @Test
    public void getCustomer() throws  Exception {
        when(customerService.getCustomerById(any())).thenReturn(customer);

        mockMvc.perform(get("api/customers/1"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk());

    }

}
```

This is how stack trace looks like:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Status 
Expected :200
Actual   :404
<Click to see difference>


    at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.fail(AssertionErrors.java:55)
    at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.assertEquals(AssertionErrors.java:82)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.StatusResultMatchers.lambda$matcher$9(StatusResultMatchers.java:619)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc$1.andExpect(MockMvc.java:195)
    at com.tinybank.tinybankapi.controllers.CustomerControllerTest.getCustomer(CustomerControllerTest.java:53)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.java:84)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

Comment: Please post the test case code and controller class code. This issue comes when url in the controller does not match with the url provided in the test.

Comment: Thank you, applying full url helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried below approach without injecting mocks?

```
MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(new CustomerController())
            .build();
```

EDIT:

I've ran your code locally.
Do this:

```
mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(new CustomerController(customerService))
            .build();
```

And add slash to the beginning of URL

```
mockMvc.perform(get("/api/customers/1"))
            .andExpect(status().isOk());
```